# How to run selenium test when Id's of DOM elements are generated dynamically?

Tags: jakarta-ee

i have recorded a test case for input form fields, after creation of test case when i try to run it, form id is dynamically generated and changes, due to which test case show error element id not found.

Answer (score 0):

element ids are not the only way of selecting in selenium. You can also use e.g. name or xpath. Have a look at this [tutorial](https://thenewcircle.com/bookshelf/selenium_tutorial/locators.html) and search stackoverflow for something like "selenium select by xpath"